# 403 Forbidden error while fetching courses list for Google Classroom

Tags: android, google-classroom, signed-apk

I have integrated Google Classroom Api's in my android application and every thing was working fine for last couple of months but now I am start getting below error every time I am trying to fetch courses list from classroom

Error:

403 Forbidden
{
    "code":403,
    "errors":[
            {
                "domain":"global",
                "message":"Google Classroom API has not been used in project google.com:api-project-60894XXXXXXX before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting
                       https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/classroom.googleapis.com/overview?project=google.com:api-project-60894XXXXXXX
                       then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
                "reason":"forbidden"
            }
        ],
        "message":"Google Classroom API has not been used in project google.com:api-project-608941808256 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting
               https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/classroom.googleapis.com/overview?project=google.com:api-project-60894XXXXXXX
               then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
        "status":"PERMISSION_DENIED"
}

Note: I have implemented Google Classroom integration from the below documentation
https://developers.google.com/classroom/quickstart/android

Also,
Every thing is working fine on my unsigned/debug build.

So my question is as I haven't disabled any permission and also it is working fine on debug/unsigned build/apk what could be the possible reason and solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You release build should use a different key than the debug one (in the classroom they create a debug one in `/.android/debug.keystore`).

The key SHA1 must be entered on Google API console, make sure your release SHA1 is entered on the console as well. Re-do the step 2.a of the classroom with the release SHA1 if needed.

Comment: Does it required another project to be create on Google API console where the signed SHA1 key is saved along with the package name ?

Comment: You don't need another project, you can a new credential to an existing project.
In the wizard proposed step 2a, you can select an existing project and go directly to step 2d (Create new credentials)